# How to set read only rights on word document?

Tags: vb.net

i need to set read only rights on word document programmatically.If somebody knows please help me.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the solution on the msdn website : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcyt0y1f.aspx.

You will need to set the property **ReadOnly** to True when you open a Word Document :

```
Me.Application.Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\Test\NewDocument.docx", ReadOnly:=True)
```